# Multiple vhosts with simple LAMP in Vagrant

Tags: linux, lamp, vagrant

I am trying to create a simple LAMP through Vagrant that can support multiple websites stored in /var/www. That can be done with vhosts.

Each project should end in .dev

Cant stand the idea creating each build that supports one project with a database each.

I cant make head or tails with Puppet or Chef. I rather avoid that, but happy to clone it from a repo.

I need some advice or point me to the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most simple straightforward Vagrant setup

https://github.com/fideloper/Vaprobash

Watch ["Apache Virtual Hosts Configuration"](http://fideloper.github.io/Vaprobash/index.html) video for quick start on creating virtual host

Dont forget to uncomment your prefered DB type before installing :)

**Bonus**: The only vagrant setup I could connect to db by Sequel Pro in seconds

Answer (score 15):

## Vagrant LAMP Multiple vhosts - UPDATED!

*See updated info below*

I've been searching ways on how to improve my web development workflow. Im currently using various tools and apps such are, LAMP, Webmin and Filezilla in Theming Projects and the like. And then I discovered the existence of this amazing tool called **Vagrant**, and after testing  it with my projects I fell in love with it and decided to integrate it to my current local web dev environment. And so I dug further and searched for possibilities on how to create and setup a **Multi Vhosts** setup with **Vagrant** using my chosen base box `Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin 32-bit`. Searching Google returns many results, but I decided to click links from stackoverflow and got landed to this question. I followed the link mentioned in `Dimitri Kouvdis`'s answer, which is a Github Repo. I've tested it and encountered issues very similar as `Dimitri Kouvdis` had also encountered. But It's already solved now, thanks to his comments, I made it worked. But during my quest in searching for my ideal ***Vagrant Box with Multiple Virtual Support***, I searched and tested several repos from Github until I found the right one for me, And I did found one. The reason I hunted down these repos because I don't know yet how to use Puppet and Chef to provision my own Dev Server, that's why.

### I've Found Another Github Repo that Worked For Me

#### Thanks To This Repo

`onema / vagrant-lamp-development`

https://github.com/onema/vagrant-lamp-development

Testing the Github Repo `Dimitri Kouvdis` had mentioned, I've encountered several issues and during that time I stopped working on it and decided to search for similar repos from Github. I found several and tested some of them including Nino Paolo's Repo (https://github.com/paolooo/vagrant-lamp). I've encountered several issues again specially during `vagrant up`. I decided again to search for another until I found and successfully setup [**onema**](https://github.com/onema/vagrant-lamp-development)'s repo. I finally decided to use and integrate this solution to my current workflow in my web development practice environment. I started loving `onema`'s repo because;

- It's easy to setup since instructions are easy to follow, specially for newbies and self-learner like me.
- It has several documentations and example setup.
- Most of all, Adding new Vhosts is easy compared to other ones I've tested.
- You can choose and setup any folder in your local drive as your source-site/project-folder.
- It's just simple without the un-necessary (in my case) Add-ons (node.js, less, etc). I just needed the LAMP Stack, plus vhost support and phpmyadmin.

### How To Set It Up - For Starters and Self-Learner Like Myself

As I mentioned it above, setup is easy (specially for newbies and self-learner like me) by reading and following the instruction found from it's Github Repo page. - https://github.com/onema/vagrant-lamp-development. You can choose to use the downloaded [**zip file**](https://github.com/onema/vagrant-lamp-development/archive/master.zip) or choose to use `git clone https://github.com/onema/vagrant-lamp-development` to copy the `Vagrant` files to your local-drive.

#### This is how I've set it up (in my *nix machine, Ubuntu 12.04 x64);

1. Download the files to your local-drive, either by using the downloaded zip files or `git` and do the basic Vagrant and VirtualBox setup. Read instruction from the [Github Page](https://github.com/onema/vagrant-lamp-development), plus do the below steps.
2. With my setup, I've edited the `Vagrantile` a bit. In `line: 70` of the orig `Vagranfle` file, I disabled NFS by putting a comment `#` to
    
   `config.vm.synced_folder "~/Sites", "/vagrant", nfs: true`

   so, it now looks like this...

   `#config.vm.synced_folder "~/Sites", "/vagrant", nfs: true`

   and then commenting out...

   `#config.vm.synced_folder "~/Sites", "/vagrant"`

   `line: 140` from the orig `Vagrantfile`

   so, it now looks like this...

   `config.vm.synced_folder "~/Sites", "/vagrant"`

   I am doing this because in my machine, during `vagrant up`, it throws several NFS related errors that I do not understand.
3. Now, for the sake of this example, and from the example from it's Repo Page, create a folder and you must name it `Sites`. This should be located in your **User Account's** folder root or your **Home Folder**. 
   `/home/your-user-account-home-folder/Sites` 
    In my case, (take note of that capital S)
    `/home/gary/Sites`

   - A.
     Create your sample dev-site/vhost and create a new folder named `wordpress.dev` and make this as the document root of your vhost `wordpress.dev` Then add your project files here. See example below;
      `/home/gary/Sites/wordpress.dev`
   - B.
     Now, reate a simple splash page for your newly created vhost so you can confirm that your configuration is redirecting you to the destination vhost root folder, when you visit the dev site from your browser. Of course, when your configurations are correct, you shall see the splash page. This is how I made my splash page.
     I created an `index.php` file and put some codes inside it,like so;

     `<?php echo "Success!!! Your wordpress.dev looks fine"; ?>`
      So when you successfully reached your vhost, you'll be greeted by the message `Success!!! Your wordpress.dev looks fine`
4. Now, add your Vagrant Box's IP Address to your `hosts` file and mapping your dev site `wordpress.dev` to it, like so; 
    `192.168.50.4 wordpress.dev` 
   Note: `192.168.50.4` is the default configured IP Address of the Vagrant Box, you may change this to your liking and update your `hosts` file.

    **In my case**, I put it like so,

   - A
      `10.10.10.10 wordpress.dev` - in my hosts file, while
   - B
     `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.10.10.10"` 
      in my Vagrantfile. 
     ***You can find this settings by looking inside your `Vagrantfile` and navigating just below this line*** 
     `# Host-Only networking required for nfs shares`
      
     Then change the `ip:` settings from there and update your `hosts` file to match the IP.
5. Edit your `Vagrantfile` again and add your vhost settings, to point to your dev site folder, add these code block like so;

   ```
   :wordpress => {
      :name => "wordpress",
      :host => "wordpress.dev", 
      :aliases => ["wordpress.dev"],
      :docroot => "/wordpress.dev"
   }
   ```

   When you added the code to the orig `Vagrantfile`, it should look like this;

   ```
    :vhost => {
       :localhost => {
       :name => "localhost",
       :host => "localhost", 
       :aliases => ["localhost.web", "dev.localhost-static.web"],
       :docroot => ""
     },
       :wordpress => {
       :name => "wordpress",
       :host => "wordpress.dev", 
       :aliases => ["wordpress.dev"],
       :docroot => "/wordpress.dev"
     }
   ```

   So your `Vagrantfile` shall now look like this one below; take note on the comma `,` right above the `w` of the `:wordpress` and right of closing curly brace `}`. 
    There should be a comma in there, when you add another vhost, you should add another comma to the right of the closing curly brace `}` of wordpress.

   ```
     Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
     config.vm.box = "precise32"
     config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"
     config.vm.host_name = "localhost"
     config.vm.provision "chef_solo"  do |chef|
       chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"    
       chef.add_recipe "vagrant_main"
       #####################################
       # MONGODB
       # https://github.com/edelight/chef-cookbooks
       #####################################
       chef.add_recipe "mongodb::10gen_repo"
       chef.add_recipe "mongodb::default"
       #####################################
       # REDIS
       # https://github.com/phlipper/chef-redis
       #####################################
       chef.add_recipe "redis"
       chef.json.merge!({
         :mysql => {
           :server_root_password => "root",
           :server_debian_password => "root",
           :server_repl_password => "root"
         },
         #####################################
         # YOU WILL NEED TO ADD THESE DOMAINS 
         # TO THE LIST OF HOSTS IN YOUR LOCAL 
         # ENVIRONMENT FOR THESE TO BE PROPERLY 
         # ROUTED
         #####################################
         :vhost => {
           :localhost => {
               :name => "localhost",
               :host => "localhost", 
               :aliases => ["localhost.web", "dev.localhost-static.web"],
               :docroot => ""
           },
           :symfony => {
                   :name => "symfony",
                   :host => "symfony.web", 
                   :aliases => ["symfony"],
                   :docroot => "/symfony/web"
           },
           :wordpress => {
               :name => "wordpress",
               :host => "wordpress.dev", 
               :aliases => ["wordpress"],
               :docroot => "/wordpress.dev"
           }
         }
       })
     end
     config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
     config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3307

     ##########################################################################
     # UNCOMMENT IF NFS IS DISABLED
     ##########################################################################
     config.vm.synced_folder "~/Sites", "/vagrant"

     ##########################################################################
     # NFS 
     # Enable if you have performance issues with large projects. 
     # see the following links for more info:
     # http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=52241&p=167041#p147056
     # http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html
     # http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/vagrant-and-nfs/
     ###########################################################################
     # Host-Only networking required for nfs shares
     config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.10.10.10"
     #config.vm.synced_folder "~/Sites", "/vagrant", nfs: true


     config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
       #   # Don't boot with headless mode
       #   vb.gui = true
       #
       #   # Use VBoxManage to customize the VM. For example to change memory:
       vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "512"]
     end
   end
   ```
6. You are now ready to start your Vagrant Box, open your terminal window 
   `ctrl + alt + t`and type in  
   `cd vagrant-lamp-development` to change directory to `vagrant-lamp-development` folder and type in 
   `vagrant up`  
   so you can start the Vagrant Box VM and then wait for it to boot-up completely. It will take several mintues for the **FIRST INITIAL BOOT UP.** Upon successful bootup, open up your browser and navigate to 
   http://wordrpress.dev
   You should see a web splash message, that you made earlier in **Step 3 B**.
7. **To Add New Vhosts**, just create a new folder inside `/home/your-home-folder/Sites/new-project-folder` and then...

   - Repeat **Steps 3B, 4A, 5**
   - If you made the changes or the addition of Vhosts to your `Vagrantfle` while the VM Box is **Running**, type..

     `vagrant provision`
     in your terminal to make the changes take effect.
   - If you made the changes or the addition of vhosts to your `Vagrantfile` while the VM Box is **OFF**, type...

     `vagrant up --provision`
     in your terminal to make the changes take effect.

     **NOTE:** The `Vagrantfile` used in this guide will download a `64-bit Precise Pangolin Basebox Base Box`, you could change it to a `32-bit Precise Pangolin Basebox` by changing the config from the `Vagrantfile`.
      I did this in my case, because I already downloaded my 32-bit base box. So I changed it to 32-bit, so I don't have to download again.

     Change...

     ```
     Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
          config.vm.box = "precise64"
          config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"
     ```

     To

     ```
     Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
             config.vm.box = "precise32"
             config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"
     ```

     ## DONE!

---

#### Other Vagrant LAMP Repos I've Tested that Worked - But not necessarily supports multiple vhosts

- [r8/vagrant-lamp](https://github.com/r8/vagrant-lamp) `Supports Multiple Vhosts`
- [mattandersen/vagrant-lamp](https://github.com/mattandersen/vagrant-lamp)
- [chad-thompson/vagrantpress](https://github.com/chad-thompson/vagrantpress)

#### Other Vagrant LAMP Repos

- [Vagrant LAMP Repo](https://github.com/search?q=vagrant-lamp&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults)

#### If you wish to use R8's Vagrant-LAMP Repo - For Multi Vhosts Purpose

[r8/vagrant-lamp](https://github.com/r8/vagrant-lamp)

Here's how to add a new `vhosts`

1. Create a new `.json` file matching your desired dev-site name, ex: `wordpress.dev` in
    `vagrant-lamp/data_bags/sites`
   So it shall look like...
   `vagrant-lamp/data_bags/sites/wordpress.json`
2. Edit the newly created file `wordpress.json` and add the following (for example only);

   ```
   {
       "id": "wordpress",
       "host": "wordpress.dev",
       "aliases": [
           "www.wordpress.dev"
       ]
   }
   ```
3. Create a new folder named `wordpress.dev` inside `vagrant-lamp/public`
    So it will look like...
   `vagrant-lamp/public/wordpress.dev`
4. Edit your `hosts` file to add and map ``` 192.168.33.10``wordpress.dev ```
   So it shall look like this...
   `192.168.33.10 wordpress.dev`
5. And you're good to go... Fire up vagrant and type `vagrant up --provision`, if the box is turned off
   If the box is turned on when you did the procedure, then type `vagrant provision` instead.
6. After this, fire up your browser and test your config, browse to `http://wordpress.dev`.
   Make sure you put some index files in there.

### The Update: Added new repository from Github.

Guys, my Linux Mint 13 (Ubuntu 12.04 based) dev box broke. That is why I had to re-install my OS (My bad... using Fake RAID & don't have a backup) from scratch again. But this time, I've used Linux Mint 17 which is based on Ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS.

So I re-installed everything from scratch and quickly setup my Web Dev environment. But it turned out that my previous working setup with vagrant no longer works. So I've searched for  solution on how to setup another web development environment that will work with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. And luckily I found a working setup with the use of another Github repo called `CPT Server`

#### The Setup

So this is how you set it up.

- Clone this repo: [cptserver](https://github.com/pigeontech/cptserver)
  Or download the zip file
- Browse to where you cloned or downloaded the repo (extract the zip file)
- Open config/config.yaml and customize how you wanted it. In my case, I did not touch any of the default configs, I just added my vhost.
- Now from your terminal, browse to where you downloaded or clone the repo and `vagrant up`

That's it! First boot will take long.

#### Adding New Virtual Host Is Easy

Just edit config/config.yaml and go to the bottom most part of the file. Look for `vhost:` line and insert your new virtualhost like this:

```
 ServerName: mydevsite.dev
    ServerAlias: mydevsite.dev
    DocumentRoot: /var/www/mydevsite.dev
    ServerAdmin: webmaster@localhost
```

Then create a new folder inside `www` and name it to match the ServerName or DocumentRoot folder `mydevsite.dev`

If you added a new host while vagrant is running, then do this; `vagrant provision`
If you modify the upper part of the config.yaml while vagrant box is running, do this; `vagrant reload --provision`

Don't forget to update the hosts file of your host machine, point your vhost to vagrant's ip.

So that's it.

Comment: Hi, I read your post although I struggled to follow everything.  Noticed you had issues with nfs errors, NFS is vital for performance. Its the Virtualbox 4.3+ bug, you should run `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.virtualbox.startup.plist` before doing `vagrant up`. Your method is way too complex to mine. I will edit my post later on

Comment: It's simple really, I just explained it in a step by step process, my post really want to target my fellow newbies and self-learner like myself. I tested several repos while waiting for your comment, and I got several issues wit the `r8` repo. `onema` repo got me no issues at all. Adding additional vhost with `onema` repo only takes editing the the `Vagrantfile`and the `hosts` file. Anyhow, just made the post for my fellow newbies.

Comment: @GaryLising lising when use r8's vagrant box I got this red error saying **default: stdin: is not a tty** do you know anything about it? thanks.

Comment: @ErdemEce - Regardless of the errors that appears on your scren, does your setup work or not? If it works you don't have to be bothered by the error. Are you on ubuntu?

Comment: @ErdemEce, Have a look here. `https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1673`. Mitchellh mentioned `Yeah this is a known "thing." It is not really a problem because it doesn't really cause a problem. Actually, the reason this error message even appears is due to a bug in Ubuntu not checking whether stdin is a TTY, and just assuming it is.`

Comment: Is it possible this can be done using [hostmanager](https://github.com/smdahlen/vagrant-hostmanager)?

Comment: I would suggest that you try it and share your results. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one too:

```
https://github.com/paolooo/vagrant-lamp
```

You can check that out.